# Preserving click functions to launch at later event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to override the click function of a link, throw an alert, then make the link fire after. That sounds a little confusing, so hopefully my code clears it up a bit:

```
        // first, find all 'a' elements with the class 'some_class'
        $('a.some_class').click(function(event)
        {
            // capture the current click event
            var current_link = $(this).click;

            // stop the current link from firing
            event.preventDefault();

            // call to the alert function
            launchAlertAndAfterAction('Hello World', current_link);
        });

        function launchAlertAndAfterAction(message, after_action)
        {
            alert(message);
            if (after_action != null && after_action != undefined)
            {
                after_action();
            }
        }
```

This code prevents the link from firing, launches the alert, but it doesn't fire the link after it pops up the message. The error is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function
```

I'm pretty sure my error lies in my code to capture the current click event ($(this).click), but I don't know enough about JavaScript to be able to get what I want.

Please let me know if I can provide additional information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `current_link` variable is not the function you want to execute, it's a jQuery click handler.

You also don't want to prevent the default event action straight away, but rather make it wait until some other result (the dialog button click) has returned.

See this [simple jsfiddle for adding a confirm action before following a link](http://jsfiddle.net/2rnxf22h/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the [location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) of your document.

like:

```
document.location.replace( myHref );
```